# is there easier way to select appropriate template specialization at runtime in c++ without exhaustive coverage?

Tags: c++, templates

Say at runtime, a variable `i` can have a value from `1` to `n`. For each case, I need to call corresponding specialization of `foo()`:

```
template<typename X>
void foo(X x) {
  ...
}
```

where `X` is to be one of `X1`, `X2`, ..., `Xn` depending on `i`.

Below is how I do it manually:

```
switch (i) {
  case 1: foo(X1()); break;
  case 2: foo(X2()); break;
  ...
  case n: foo(Xn()); break;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Even worse, if `bar()` takes two template parameters, then I'd have to do:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
void bar(X x, Y y) {
  ...
}

int main() {
   ...
   if (i == 1 && j == 1) bar(X1(), Y1());
   else if (i == 1 && j == 2) bar(X1(), Y2());
   ...
   else if (i == 2 && j == 1) bar(X2(), Y1());
   ...
   else /* (i == n && j == m) */ bar(Xn(), Ym());
}
```

Wondering if there is a better / more clever way to do this.

Comment: Templates and "at runtime" don't mix. The way you described the problem, no, there's no better way. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), frankly. What real-life problem do you need to solve where you think this might be helpful?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::variant` and its `std::visit`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My intended application is that the function's performance is absolutely critical (it needs to be called 1M times). Hence, I'm trying to avoid any unnecessary indirections (e.g., dynamic dispatch, conditional, etc) within the function. Essentially, I want to prepare n optimized functions for each of the n cases and choose one at runtime.

Comment: I'd write it the naive way first and profile.  If the profiler doesn't peg that implementation as the bottleneck, don't worry about it.

Comment: 1 million times is only a lot if your function is taking longer than 1 second to run

Comment: And to add on, if this truly is your bottleneck, just use a python script or something to generate the `switch`, lookup tables, etc.  Generate the code using your build system and never think about it again.

Comment: If you don't have things profiled, it's likely you guessed wrong, and commenters here will endlessly harangue you about it.

Comment: If things become too complicated you probably started of with the wrong design. For runtime selection of functionality use runtime polymorphism, do not mix it with static polymorphism (templates). The class your foo function is using is very likely to have some semantic meaning you can model using an abstract virtual function. If so derive ALL your X's from an abstract base class and call that virtual function from foo.

Comment: @PasserBy I think OP hasn't even mentioned a performance issue. At the moment it is not even relevant, because he still has a design issue to fix first.

Comment: @PepijnKramer OP mentioned it's an attempt at optimization in the comments. And it may in fact be a valid one, but we wouldn't know because there's simply not enough information.

Comment: In its current form, you could replace the `switch` with `[&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) { ((i==I && (foo<I+1>(X<I+1>{}), true)) || ...); }(std::make_index_sequence<n>{});` if `X` is actually a class template too - but perhaps you should make `foo`  a `virtual` member function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is only one parameter, your manual approach is probably best. It's readable, and at some point you need to perform exactly that logic. That is, you need some sort of lookup to switch between function calls at runtime.

I'll also echo some advice from the comments that you should make sure this is a real issue, not just an expected issue. Historically, many hours (years?) have been spent optimizing the wrong parts of various projects, resulting in no real benefit (but with a real maintenance cost since the code became more complex).

---

If there are multiple parameters that can vary in type, then the manual approach does get bogged down. You still need a lookup of some sort to pick the function call at runtime, but perhaps you can hand off many of the details to the compiler. A little template magic could generate a lookup table for you. The magic is overkill for a single parameter, but it comes in handy when the number of parameters increases.

*I am going to take the question at face value in that the parameters are to be default constructed. However, I will change one detail in the numbering. Numbering in C++ is typically 0-based, not 1-based, so I'm going to assume there is an `X0` and no `Xn`. This will make an array implementation smoother. The idea is to create an multi-dimensional array of function pointers that will serve as your lookup table. Use your `i` and `j` as indices to get the desired function. (You wanted raw efficiency, right? So I've used function pointers instead of `std::function`.)*

The template magic is a bit esoteric. There's a recursive class template definition, where each instantiation is responsible for defining a function template named `make()` that will return a possibly multi-dimensional array of function pointers (except for the base case, which will return a single function pointer; each recursion adds a dimension to the array). It is also responsible for defining a type alias, `MakeType`, for the type of the array being returned by `make()`. (While it is possible to get by without the alias, the code is easier to grasp with it.) At each stage of the recursion, one parameter is removed from the class template and one parameter is added to the `make()` template. The removed parameter is a tuple of the choices for the type of one parameter; the added parameter is one type from this tuple.

Yes, this is designed to handle an arbitrary number of parameters, not just two. I'm going with the rule of thumb that sometimes a generic approach leads to cleaner code than focusing on a specific use case.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ToInvoke, typename... Params>
struct Invoker; // No definition yet.

// Base case:
template <typename ToInvoke>
struct Invoker<ToInvoke> {
    // This is the effective signature of the functions:
    using MakeType = void (*)();
    
    template <typename... Values>
    static constexpr MakeType make() {
        // Returning a function pointer; the function is not invoked here.
        return ToInvoke::template invoke<Values...>;
    }
};

// Recursive case:
template<typename ToInvoke, typename Param0, typename... Params>
struct Invoker<ToInvoke, Param0, Params...> {
    // For readability:

    static constexpr auto param_size = std::tuple_size_v<Param0>; // Number of alternatives for this parameter
    template <std::size_t Index>
    using ParamType = std::tuple_element_t<Index, Param0>;        // Type of each alternative
    using Recurse = Invoker<ToInvoke, Params...>;                 // The recursive case (remove the first parameter)

    // Needed for recursion:

    // We will make an array. The length is the number of alternatives.
    // The elements are created by the recursive case.
    using MakeType = std::array<typename Recurse::MakeType, param_size>;

    // Make the array. Each alternative for the first parameter is appended
    // to `Values...` then given to the recursive case to get elements
    // for this array.
    template <typename... Values>
    static constexpr MakeType make() {
        // Immediately invoked lambda (to extract the indices):
        return []<std::size_t... Index>(std::index_sequence<Index...>) {
            return MakeType{ Recurse::template make<Values..., ParamType<Index>>()... };
        }(std::make_index_sequence<param_size>{});
    }
};
```

See? That's a lot of overhead. For the one-parameter case, the manual approach is cleaner.

Okay, so once you have this template defined, how is it used? Well, one pesky detail is that a function template cannot be a template template parameter, so we need a wrapper for your function template. As a bonus, this wrapper will default-construct the parameters, which conveniently gives a uniform signature when invoking the wrapper. *For this demonstration, I've expanded your function to three parameters and renamed it `baz`.*

```cpp
struct baz_caller {
    template<typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
    static void invoke() { baz(X{}, Y{}, Z{}); }
};
```

So now, you just need to define some tuples with the desired types and call the appropriate `make()`. When you want to invoke a function, the indices to the types become indices to the array.

```cpp
// Define the valid parameter types.
using Xs = std::tuple<X0, X1, X2, X3>;
using Ys = std::tuple<Y0, Y1, Y2>;
using Zs = std::tuple<Z0, Z1>;

// Make a multi-dimensional array of function pointers.
constexpr auto bazzer = Invoker<baz_caller, Xs, Ys, Zs>::make<>();

int main () {
    unsigned i = 1, j = 1, k = 0;
    bazzer[i][j][k]();       // X1, Y1, Z0
    bazzer[--i][++j][++k](); // X0, Y2, Z1
}
```

One thing you lose with this approach is the ability to easily detect out-of-bounds indices (with a `default` on your `switch`). You might want to add some range checking around the call site, or you could change the sub-scripting from `operator[]` to `at()`.

Comment: holy moly. this works! this trick is exactly what i was looking for. thank you so much. now, i have to sit down and spend some time to understand what is going on :)